# Detect token transaction to a contract

Tags: solidity

Is there a way to detect when my contract receive tokens? I don’t own the token contract, I only want to know the address and amount of token sent to my contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know which token your contract expects to receive, you can listen for a `Transfer` event issued by the token contract. (Not your contract!)

The standard [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) `Transfer` event looks like this:

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
```

...so listen to the token contract for an event where `_to` is the address of your contract.

If you don't have a specific contract in mind and you want to know when ownership of *any* token is transferred to your contract, you would theoretically need to listen for any `Transfer` event from any contract on the blockchain with your contract's address in the `_to` field. Unfortunately the available tools will mostly assume that you want to listen to the events of a particular contract, so this may be difficult to do in practice.

The above approach only works for a process outside the blockchain, that is able to listen for logs. Most commonly this would be JavaScript code using the `watch` and `listen` functions in `web3.js`. If you want your Solidity contract code to respond to an ERC 20 transfer then you're probably out of luck; A standard ERC20 token won't call your contract's code for you in the way that a normal ETH transfer would. In theory you might be able to incentivize someone to listen for the events and send a transaction to relay that information to your contract, possibly with a merkle proof to show that they really saw what they are suggesting in the logs, but this wouldn't be trivial to do. Alternatively you may be able to set up a workflow such that the user calls your contract to make the transaction happen, and your contract in turn calls the token contract; That way your contract knows about the transfer because it directed the transfer itself. The `approve` and `transferFrom` methods in the ERC20 standard are designed for cases like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was what I thought. Unfortunately, I want the contract to be completely decentralized and the token contract didn’t implement approve.

Comment: One more option might be to wrap the original token contract with a more advanced proxy contract that implements approve, or other code you need. However, you'd have to get your users using your proxy contract.